# Error when trying to use SendGrid.

Tags: c#, sendgrid

Can someone please help me before I pull my hair out!

I am trying to use the SendGrid API within my C# web application but it does not work.

The error is this:

"the type or namespace 'SendGridMessage' could not be found...."

Now, I followed a guide to do this perfectly and it should by rights work but for some reason it does not.  I'm hoping someone out there has the answer :)

Here are some details of my project:

Framework 4.5.2
I've added the SendGrid package via NUGET.

See the attached image..[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvgyY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please Use sendgrid latest version to lower version.

i guess you used 8.0 to 6.0

you may downgrade version from nuget package

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

I was using the incorrect version of sendGrid with the email code!